# update record based on mutiple queries to related (sort of) objects

Tags: apex, class, invocable-method

My objective:

Once an Opportunity is Closed/Won and the quote is the primary, look up the product2 related to the quote line(custom) and find the related subscription plan(custom) and pricebook(custom) and return those Ids (via lookup fields) to the quote line(custom).

I need to traverse Opp > quote > quote line > product2 > subscription plan lines > subscription plan where I can get the Subscription Plan Id (custom) and the pricebook Id(custom). There are many pricebooks(custom) on the subscription plan so I also have to look up the name of the standard pricebook and the isocurrency from the quote and then concatenate them to have the name of the custom pricebook I need to find. 
Clear as mud?

Here is what I have come up with so far, after multiple iterations. I've written it to be used in the Process Builder and I tried a trigger, too - not sure which way is best. There is another update that happens after the fields on the quote line are updated that will take all of that data and create a subscription(custom) - but baby steps, I need to get this one working for now. I get no errors when I run this, but it updates all the records with the same Subscription plan and Pricebook. I understand it has something to do with setting the IDs, but I am unsure of how else to do this.

```
    public static void quoteLineItemGetSubPlanPricebook(List<Id> OppoIds){

        Id QID;
        Id QLID;
        Id SubPlanId;
        Id PriceBookNSId;
        String SFPriceBookName;
        String NSPriceBookName;
        String CurrencyCode;
        Boolean FDAresult = false;
        Boolean STDresult = false;
        list<Id> QLIDs = new list<Id>();
        list<Id> QLIprod = new list<Id>();
        list<Id> SubplanList = new list<Id>();
        list<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> recordsToUpdate = new list<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>();


        //Get the primary quote from the opportunity
        list<SBQQ__Quote__c> quo = [SELECT CurrencyIsoCode, SBQQ__PriceBook__r.Name, SBQQ__Account__c, SBQQ__Opportunity2__c, SBQQ__Primary__c FROM SBQQ__Quote__c where SBQQ__Opportunity2__c in :OppoIds AND SBQQ__Primary__c = TRUE];
        for(SBQQ__Quote__c qt: quo){
            QID = qt.Id; //add quote id to the list Qlist
            SFPriceBookName = qt.SBQQ__PriceBook__r.Name; //get the name of the SF Pricebook to use to choose PriceBook(NetSuite)
            CurrencyCode = qt.CurrencyIsoCode; // get the Currency code to use to choose PriceBook(NetSuite)
            FDAresult = SFPriceBookName.contains('FDA');
            STDresult = SFPriceBookName.contains('ISO');
                if(FDAresult = True){
                NSPriceBookName = 'FDA '  +CurrencyCode;
                } else if (STDresult = True){
                  NSPriceBookName = 'STD '  +CurrencyCode;  
                }
        }        


        //get the QuoteLines from the Quote
        list<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> newQLI = [SELECT SBQQ__Product__c, SBQQ__Quantity__c, SBQQ__Quote__c, Id FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c where SBQQ__Quote__c = : QID];
        for(SBQQ__QuoteLine__c q: newQLI){
            QLID = q.Id; //add the id to QLID
            QLIDs.add(q.Id); // add all of the Quoteline Ids to the list QLIDs
            QLIprod.add(q.SBQQ__Product__c); //add all of the Product2 Ids to the list QLIprod

        }


        //get the subscription plan lines using the product2 id 
        list<sbilling_conn__Subscription_Plan_Lines__c> subpl = [SELECT sbilling_conn__Product__c, sbilling_conn__Subscription_Plan__c FROM sbilling_conn__Subscription_Plan_Lines__c where sbilling_conn__Product__c in :QLIprod];
        for(sbilling_conn__Subscription_Plan_Lines__c spl: subpl){
           SubplanList.add(spl.sbilling_conn__Subscription_Plan__c); //add the subscription plan Ids to the list SubplanList
           SubPlanId = spl.sbilling_conn__Subscription_Plan__c;
        }


        //get the pricebook from the 
        list<sbilling_conn__Price_Book_Custom__c> pbNetSuite = [SELECT Id, Name, sbilling_conn__Subscription_Plan__c FROM sbilling_conn__Price_Book_Custom__c where sbilling_conn__Subscription_Plan__c in :SubplanList AND Name = :NSPriceBookName];
        for(sbilling_conn__Price_Book_Custom__c pbs: pbNetSuite){
            PriceBookNSId = pbs.id;
        }

                for(SBQQ__QuoteLine__c q: newQLI){
               recordsToUpdate.add(new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c(
                   id = q.Id,
                     Subscription_Plan__c  = SubPlanId,
                     Price_Book_NetSuite__c = PriceBookNSId
                 ));
                }



        update recordsToUpdate;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can do some system debugs to know which line is causing this issue. I was looking at your code and maybe it's one of your queries. or how you add values to the id's maybe it can be a set instead of a list. i can't help enough since I can't do proper debugging to know which line is causing the issue.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the debug log shows that the QuoteLine Id is iterating but the other Ids are static. Which makes sense the way I have it set up - what I am not sure how to do is to associate the other Ids (Subscription Plan and Pricebook) with the Quote Line Id to update without putting the queries in the for loops, which obviously I do not want to (and cannot) do.